# c++ templately template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, specifications

I have a template function, which has no argument

```
template<typename T>
T cast() {
    return T();
}
```

I want to specialize it for some templated class like vector like

```
template<typename T>
template<>
vector<T> cast<vector<T>>() {
    // something special
    return vector<T>()
}
```

since it takes no argument, so it cannot be overloaded.
What should I do to implement it?

Comment: Partially specializing functions is not a thing. You can either create a class with a static function and partially specialize the class or select when the function should operate with SFINAE techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Functions cannot be partial specialized.

You might

- provide another customization point

  - class which can be partial specialized:

    ```
    template <typename T>
    struct impl
    {
        T operator()() const { return T(); }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct impl<std::vector<T>>
    {
        std::vector<T> operator()() const { /*Something special*/ return std::vector<T>(); }
    };

    template<typename T>
    T cast() {
        return impl<T>{}();
    }
    ```
  - forward to overload functions with "tag":

    ```
    template <typename T>
    T impl(std::struct_identity<T>)
    {
        return T();
    };

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T> impl(std::struct_identity<std::vector<T>>)
    {
        /*Something special*/
        return std::vector<T>();
    };

    template<typename T>
    T cast() {
        return impl(std::struct_identity<T>{});
    }
    ```
- Create the different (exclusive) overloads (from the start):

  ```
  // traits to detect std::vector
  template <typename T>
  struct is_vector : std::false_type {};

  template <typename T, typename A>
  struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> : std::true_type {};

  template<typename T, std::enale_if_t<!is_vector<T>::value, int> = 0>
  T cast() {
      return T();
  }

  template<typename T, std::enale_if_t<is_vector<T>::value, int> = 0>
  T cast() {
      /*Something special*/
      return T();
  }
  ```
- or since C++17, use `if constexpr`:

  ```
  // traits to detect std::vector
  template <typename T>
  struct is_vector : std::false_type {};

  template <typename T, typename A>
  struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> : std::true_type {};

  template<typename T>
  T cast() {
      if constexpr(is_vector<T>::value) {
          /*Something special*/
          return T();
      } else {
          return T();
      }
  }
  ```
- or since C++20, you might overload with constraint:

  ```
  // traits to detect std::vector
  template <typename T>
  struct is_vector : std::false_type {};

  template <typename T, typename A>
  struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> : std::true_type {};

  template<typename T>
  T cast() {
      return T();
  }

  template<typename T>
  requires(is_vector<T>)
  T cast() {
      /*Something special*/
      return T();
  }
  ```

Comment: You can also use the SFINAE to achieve pretty much the same results as with `requires` just without the need for C++20.

Comment: @ALX23z: But you have to handle that from start. `template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_vector<T>, int> = 0> T cast()` (In that case, proposing `if constexpr` would also be an alternative). After re-read original post, not sure if "overload set" is known at start or not.

Comment: yep. There are restrictions and nuances but it doesn't mean that this isn't a viable solution - the question isn't specific enough to determine that. It is up to the OP whether or not it suits them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, SFNIAE really meet my expectation

Comment: @ALX23z: Add alternative (without customization points).